# How can i change route url in CanJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, canjs

I have route.attr:

```
can.route.attr({type:"list",id:"list",val:""})

location.hash -> "#!update/edit&val=113"
```

how can I change this to #!list/list and destroy val:"" in url

i use this : `can.route.attr({type:"list",id:"list",val:null})`

```
location.hash -> "#!update/edit&val="
```

Comment: I had resolve this problem: use: route.attr({type:"list", id:"list"},true)

Answer (score 1):

Much like other `can.Map`s, completely removing a key from `can.route` requires using `can.route.removeAttr("val")`.  Try it; you should see `&val=` disappear from the hash entirely.